# Limit search results per CPT (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, search

Im currently building a search filter. But my problem is that I can't figure out how to limit search results per custom post type. The search function:

```
function ledvionSearchResults($data) { 
  $mainQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page', 'category', 'product'),
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    's' => sanitize_text_field($data['term'])
  ));

  $results = array(
    'products' => array(), 
    'categories' => array(),
    'generalInfo' => array()
  );

  while($mainQuery->have_posts()) {
    $mainQuery->the_post();

    if (get_post_type() == 'product') { 
      array_push($results['products'], array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
        'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(), 
        'ean' => get_field('barcode'),
        'sku' => get_field('sku')
      ));
    }

    if (get_post_type() == 'category') {
      array_push($results['categories'], array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'permalink' => get_the_permalink()
      ));
    }

    if (get_post_type() == 'post' OR get_post_type() == 'page') {
      array_push($results['generalInfo'], array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'permalink' => get_the_permalink()
      ));
    }
  }

  return $results;

}
```

I have tried to merge multiple queries but that didnt seem to work and I tried the pre_get_posts action but that would only work for one or all custom post types. Example below:

```
function ledvion_adjust_queries($query){
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search && !is_post_type_archive('product')) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('product'));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
    $query->set('orderby', 'title');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
  } 

  return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ledvion_adjust_queries');
```

Comment: With your first approach, you could simply `count` the already existing items in the specific array, and only do the array_push, if that number is still below your threshold …